# Appending data in a if statement

Tags: functions, conditional

I'm new to Mathematica, only installed it just now.

I have some data in the following format.

```
data = {{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0.8, 0.5, 0.2}, {0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0.},....
```

The majority of the inner lists are empty, and I want to remove those. This gives rise to two questions. What would be the 'most Mathematica' approach to this?

And second question, why isn't my approach working? (my interpretation of how this code would work in comments.

```
d = {};  (* create an empty list*)
If[Mean[#] != 0, Append[d, #]] & /@ data; (*for each item in data, if the mean of that item is not 0, append that item to d *)
```

The output this gives is an empty d, i.e. d=={}

Comment: Use `AppendTo` instead of `Append`. The latter has no side effects. Another way could be `Pick[data, 
 UnitStep[Abs[data].ConstantArray[1., 3] - 100. $MachineEpsilon], 1]`.

Comment: Ah, and welcome on Mathematica.StackExchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the most idiomatic approach.  One might say along the lines that you propose that this is asking for the "most Mathematical" approach, but that is too ambiguous.  Since it is now the Wolfram Language, I propose that we are talking about the "most wolfish" approach.  That is probably

```
fakedata = RandomChoice[{0.8, 0.2} -> {0, 1}, {25, 3}]
Cases[fakedata, x_ /; 0 != Mean[x]]
```

However, I love to use `Map` whenever possible, so I neverthelss lean towards

```
If[0 != Mean[#], #, Nothing] & /@ fakedata
```

Implicit in your example is that all entries will be nonnegative.  My proposals therefore make this assumption as well.

**Edit:**

My answers above use your assumption to maximize comparability with your example.  If that assumption might not hold, you can readily modify them to the following:

```
Cases[fakedata, x_ /; {0, 0, 0} != x]
If[{0, 0, 0} != #, #, Nothing] & /@ fakedata
```

However, once we go that far, I prefer as most "wolfish" the answer of @JohnDoty, which becomes

```
fakedata/.{0,0,0}->Nothing
```

The one drawback of relying on pattern matching is evinced by my need to switch to integer zeros to match my `fakedata`.

Comment: @anderstood That's already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Sorry I had missed that.

Answer (score 3):

```
data/.{0.,0.,0.}->Nothing
```

or

```
Select[data, # != {0., 0., 0.} &]
```

or

```
DeleteCases[data, {0., 0., 0.}]
```